# QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'user_id' cannot be null

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, postman, dml

I have 3 files: controller, service and dao.
I want to do the function readPost, but when using postman, it seems to be stuck in the createPost function inside postDao.
please help me..

DAO

```
const createPost = async (user_id, contents, posting_id, image_url) => {

  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO postings ( user_id, contents ) 
    VALUE (?, ?)`,
    [user_id, contents]
  ),

  const post = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO posting_images ( posting_id, image_url )
    VALUE (?, ?)`,
    [posting_id, image_url]
  );
  return post;
};

const readPost = async () => {

  const postings = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT 
      p.user_id, u.profile_image, 
      p_i.posting_id, p_i.image_url, p.contents
    FROM users u
    JOIN postings p
    ON u.id = p.user_id
    JOIN posting_images p_i
    ON p.id = p_i.posting_id`
  );
  return postings;
};

module.exports = { createPost, readPost };
```

Comment: `VALUE` should be `VALUES`

Comment: I fixed it with VALUES but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try like this?

Reference [mySQL insert](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-insert)

```
const createPost = async (user_id, contents, posting_id, image_url) => {

  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO postings ( user_id, contents ) 
    VALUES (?, ?)`,
    [user_id, contents]
  ),

  const post = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO posting_images ( posting_id, image_url )
    VALUES (?, ?)`,
    [posting_id, image_url]
  );
  return post;
};
```

Comment: createPost is running fine.
I get the same error even after modifying as follows.
```
const createPost = async (user_id, contents) => {

   const post =  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO postings ( user_id, contents ) 
    VALUES (?, ?)`,
    [user_id, contents]
  )  
return post;
};
```

Comment: @ggyoE could you check in the network tab if user_id is sent with a value?

Comment: please again explain in an easy way.

Comment: @ggyoE right click on the browser where your application is open, then go to network tab, you will see a POST api call failing, check if you are sending user_id there!

Comment: I'm checking with postman, but I don't see the network tab
I wrote and executed editPost, deletePost, etc. under readPost, but the corresponding functions are being called well, but why is only readPost blocked in createPost?

Comment: I solved it! In this part, ```const readPost = async () => {
  return await postDao.createPost();
};``` I was calling the CreatePost function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ggyoE You're welcome. please answer  your own question and mark it as solved!!